# Wrong PL/SQL - Too many values/Missing right paranthesis

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have these 2 tables:

[image: TST_DEPARTMENTS]

[image: TST_EMPLOTEES]

I have this piece of code that don't work no matter what and I do not know what's the problem, it goes from "TOO MANY VALUES" to "MISSING RIGHT PARANTHESIS" at another try but I have all of them.

I started from this code and tried to find mistakes :

```
    DECLARE
      CURSOR c IS 
           SELECT * FROM employees
           ORDER BY sal DESC;
      l c%ROWTYPE;
             
    BEGIN
      OPEN c;
      LOOP
        FETCH c INTO l;
        EXIT WHEN c%NOTFOUND;
        UPDATE employees
               SET salary=salary*(1+ (SELECT ((avg_salary-salary)+5)/100 
                                       FROM (SELECT AVG(salary) AS avg_salary 
                                                 FROM employees emp
                                                      JOIN department dep
                                                           ON emp.department_id=dep.row_id
                                                 GROUP BY dep.row_id) s
                                       WHERE s.department_id=employees.department_id))
               WHERE emno=l.empno;
        COMMIT;
      END LOOP;
    END;
    /
```

And I ended up with this, that's still not working: - TOO MANY VALUES

```
 DECLARE
  CURSOR c_crs IS 
       SELECT * FROM tst_employees
       ORDER BY salary DESC;
  l_rec c_crs%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN
  OPEN c_crs;
  LOOP
    FETCH c_crs INTO l_rec;
    EXIT WHEN c_crs%NOTFOUND;
    UPDATE tst_employees emp
           SET salary=salary*(1+ (SELECT ((s.avg_salary-empl.salary)+5)/100
                                 FROM 
                                    (SELECT dep.department_id, AVG(emp.salary) AS avg_salary 
                                    FROM tst_employees emp
                                           JOIN tst_departments dep
                                                 ON emp.department_id=dep.department_id
                                    GROUP BY dep.department_id) s, tst_employees emp
                                 WHERE s.department_id=emp.department_id ))
            WHERE emp.employee_id=l_rec.employee_id;
      COMMIT;
  END LOOP;
  CLOSE c_crs;
END;
/
```

or this: -- MISSING RIGHT PARANTHESIS:

```
DECLARE
  CURSOR c_crs IS 
       SELECT * FROM tst_employees
       ORDER BY salary DESC;
  l_rec c_crs%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN
  OPEN c_crs;
  LOOP
    FETCH c_crs INTO l_rec;
    EXIT WHEN c_crs%NOTFOUND;
    UPDATE tst_employees te
           SET salary=salary*(1+ (SELECT empl.employee_id, empl.department_id, ((s.avg_salary-empl.salary)+5)/100
                                 FROM 
                                    (SELECT dep.department_id, AVG(emp.salary) AS avg_salary 
                                    FROM tst_employees emp
                                           JOIN tst_departments dep
                                                 ON emp.department_id=dep.department_id
                                    GROUP BY dep.department_id) s, tst_employees empl
                                 WHERE s.department_id=empl.department_id
                                ORDER BY empl.employee_id ))
            WHERE te.employee_id=l_rec.employee_id;
      COMMIT;
  END LOOP;
  CLOSE c_crs;
END;
/
```

Please help me fix the main code so it can work and recalculate the salaries as needed, I have no other idea why it doesn't work. I want to raise the salaries based on the formula in the update clause (s.avg_salary-empl.salary)+5)/100 , based on the each employee's department's average salary

Comment: What is your end goal? Uou haven't stated what you are actually trying to achieve with your code.

Comment: What is this part supposed to do ? "salary*(1+ (SELECT employee_id..." ? You cannot multiply a number (salary) with multiple columns

Comment: @KoenLostrie you're right, i let this part in the big code when i copied the SELECT back after testing it separately.

Comment: You're joining on a column row_id but that is not in your table descriptions - which one is wrong table desc or your statement ?

Comment: your second code makes no sense  as the inner query is supposed to return a single number - not several columns.

Comment: Why don't you start with removing the cursor and try your select statements for one employee_id and see if you get the desired result? Then try to update just one salary. Once you got that working you can use the cursor

Comment: also, your first inner query returns multiple rows instead of a single number

Comment: There are multiple issues in your code... a bit to much to give a clear answer. It looks like you wrote a big chunk of code and now you're trying to fix it. Instead, you could start with a small piece of code: a select to get the average per department id. Test it and verify it shows the correct results. Then incorporate that in a more complex select: a select with the salary per employee and average salary for the employee department. Test and verify. Continue until you have what you want.

Comment: Note that that formula will result in a salary reduction for employees whose salary is higher than the average - is that intended ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you have a cursor for all employees and loop through them one at a time when all of the employees can have their salaries updated with a single update statement.  Looping through them one at a time would also give the employees a the end of the loop a larger raise because with each loop, the average for each department would be going up as each update is applied.

A simple update statement like this one should work:

```
UPDATE tst_employees te
   SET salary =
             salary
           * (  (  (  (  (SELECT AVG (salary)
                            FROM tst_employees te2
                           WHERE te2.department_id = te.department_id)
                       - empl.salary)
                    + 5)
                 / 100)
              + 1);
```